# Not receiving PAYMENT_UPDATED event for payment webhooks

Tags: api, webhooks, square-connect

I was able to use square's webhook API based on descriptions here, https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#webhooks-overview 
and payment webhook was working fine.

Recently, I noticed that after completing a cash payment my webhook event handler
is not receiving any PAYMENT_UPDATED notifications.

I'm able to get the Test Webhook Notification trigger with my event handler service and I did register the PAYMENT_UPDATED webhook for my location.

This service was working before, is there any new changes for square-connect api?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the webhooks notification will successfully go through. If it fails for any reason, Square will not attempt to resend it. You should definitely use alternate methods (such as the ListTransactions endpoint) to fully verify the data.